# Why does the second query in spring jpa doesn't occur so the data is stale?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.3.4.RELEASE` as my parent pom and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as my dependency.
There is a breakpoint on the line `City city2 = cityRepository.findById(20L).orElseGet(null);`

First, I invoke the method `m2` and the program hangs on breakpoint and it shows `city1.name` is `ocean`.
Then I invoke the method `m1` with parameter `name = land`, and it stores in the backend database.
Finally, I resume the breakpoint, but `city2.name` is still `ocean`! If I enable jpa log by adding `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` in `application.properties`, it shows that the program will never query backend database on the line `City city2 = cityRepository.findById(20L).orElseGet(null);`

I'm so confused about it because `city2` is stale!
Here is my source code:

`Controller.java`

```
    @PostMapping("/m1")
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
    public Object m1(@RequestParam String name){
        City city = new City();
        city.setId(20L);
        city.setName(name);
        city.setState("on");
        cityRepository.save(city);
        return city;
    }

    @GetMapping("/m2")
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
    public Object m2(){
        City city1 = cityRepository.findById(20L).orElseGet(null);
        // breakpoint here
        City city2 = cityRepository.findById(20L).orElseGet(null);
        return city2;
    }
```

`City.java`

```
@Data
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONE)
public class City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

aren't you calling the **repository with the  same input parameter** so it makes sense to return you the same result

Comment: Yes, the input parameter is the same. But my purpose is that it makes two query from db, but not one.